# Restricting other Windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

i am working on WPF and have a problem i.e. I want to restrict Windows 8 machine from running other application when my application started.
I know Windows 8 allows us to run only specified application using "gpedit.msc" but i want it through C# so that administrator does not have to go through all those steps for allowing specified application.

Comment: Beside the feasibility of that, do you really want to require your application to be run as admin? Because it is very likely you will have to in order to make system changes.

Comment: No Samuel actually not required.

Comment: That was not the question. You want that your app mess with system functionality that requires admin privileges. If you, by what ever means, can bring the functionality into your app then you most probably need to force the application to be executed as admin user, therefore require every user to be admin, which may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Process class.

a call to GetProcesses will return an array of currently active processes.

when you find the one you want to shutdown you can try these methods on that proves:

if(!process.CloseMainWindow())
   process.Kill();

Comment: IMHO this is a very bad idea. You will need either a black or whitelist for that to ensure you do not kill any wrong process which is not trivial to do. This task is really designed for group policies.

Comment: Yes he will have to be careful.